# Merging the copy-paste process from two locations to one location

Tags: excel, vba

How can I merge the process from pasting the values at two locations to one location?. For example in the following sub-code. I want to merge these two rows and want to paste in destSht only

```
C.Offset(1, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 
 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 1) = C.Offset(1, 8).Value
```

Above code is sub-code of the following code

```
Set destSht = Worksheets("Final")
  With ActiveSheet

  For Each C In .Range("A17", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
  If .Cells(C.Row, "A") = "Element: Linear" Then
  C.Offset(1, 7).Value = "Straight"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) = C.Offset(1, 7).Value

  C.Offset(1, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 1) = C.Offset(1, 8).Value

  C.Offset(1, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 2) = C.Offset(1, 9).Value

  ElseIf .Cells(C.Row, "A") = "Element: Circular" Then
  C.Offset(3, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[3]C[-4]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, -3) = C.Offset(3, 6).Value

  C.Offset(3, 7).Value = "Arc"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) = C.Offset(3, 7).Value

  C.Offset(3, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C[-6]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 1) = C.Offset(3, 8).Value

  C.Offset(3, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C[-5]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 2) = C.Offset(3, 9).Value
```

Comment: `destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = "Straight"`?

Comment: @BigBen As you can see in Full code, I'm copying the values from another cells (except for Straight part)..I should have given following code for example........C.Offset(1, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 1) = C.Offset(1, 8).Value

Comment: Then take the R1C1 logic you currently have in formula version and convert it to an `Offset` equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, Didn't understand...I'm new to VBA...Can you please explain little bit more

Comment: First, do you understand [how R1C1 notation works](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm)?

Comment: Yup, Understand !....But can't figure out, how to implement ithis specific case (As you mentioned above)

Comment: `=RC[-6]"`as an example, is equivalent to `Offset(,-6)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it correct

```
 With Worksheets("Source")     
 For Each C In .Range("A17", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
If .Cells(C.Row, "A") = "Element: Linear" Then
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Straight"
  C.Offset(1, 2).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
  C.Offset(1, 3).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)
  C.Offset(1, 4).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)
  C.Offset(3, 2).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)
ElseIf .Cells(C.Row, "A") = "Element: Circular" Then
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Arc"
  C.Offset(1, 2).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
  C.Offset(1, 3).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)
  C.Offset(1, 4).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)
  C.Offset(14, 2).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)
```